# Deserialize Json to an object

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

though i have been old school developing for some years now, i need some help on how to display this json to a listview.

JSON returned from URL

```
[
   {
      "LastUpdated":"09/10/2019 09:08:02",
      "Latitude":-33.917713,
      "Longitude":18.431315,
      "PlannedEndDate":"",
      "Reported":"09/10/2019 09:00:38",
      "StartDate":"09/10/2019 09:00:38",
      "ID":"WC-ATMS-196763",
      "RegionName":"Western Cape",
      "CountyName":null,
      "Severity":"none",
      "RoadwayName":"Table Bay Blvd",
      "DirectionOfTravel":"Inbound",
      "Description":null,
      "Location":"0.0 km after N2 Elevated Freeway",
      "LanesAffected":null,
      "LanesStatus":null,
      "LcsEntries":null,
      "NavteqLinkId":"771421441",
      "PrimaryLocation":null,
      "SecondaryLocation":null,
      "FirstArticleCity":null,
      "SecondCity":null,
      "EventType":"TrafficConditions",
      "EventSubType":"Mainline Congestion",
      "MapEncodedPolyline":null
   },
   {
      "LastUpdated":"09/10/2019 09:30:02",
      "Latitude":-26.0378,
      "Longitude":28.016144,
      "PlannedEndDate":"",
      "Reported":"09/10/2019 08:08:25",
      "StartDate":"09/10/2019 08:08:25",
      "ID":"GP-ATMS-207804",
      "RegionName":"Gauteng",
      "CountyName":null,
      "Severity":"minor",
      "RoadwayName":"N1",
      "DirectionOfTravel":"Southbound",
      "Description":null,
      "Location":"0.7 km before Ramp from William Nicol I/C",
      "LanesAffected":null,
      "LanesStatus":null,
      "LcsEntries":null,
      "NavteqLinkId":"837759156",
      "PrimaryLocation":null,
      "SecondaryLocation":null,
      "FirstArticleCity":null,
      "SecondCity":null,
      "EventType":"TrafficConditions",
      "EventSubType":"Ramp Congestion",
      "MapEncodedPolyline":null
   },
   {
      "LastUpdated":"09/10/2019 09:52:20",
      "Latitude":-33.944828,
      "Longitude":18.472132,
      "PlannedEndDate":"",
      "Reported":"09/10/2019 09:49:42",
      "StartDate":"09/10/2019 09:49:42",
      "ID":"WC-ATMS-196773",
      "RegionName":"Western Cape",
      "CountyName":null,
      "Severity":"none",
      "RoadwayName":"N2",
      "DirectionOfTravel":"Inbound",
      "Description":null,
      "Location":"0.0 km after Ramp to Mowbray Main",
      "LanesAffected":null,
      "LanesStatus":null,
      "LcsEntries":null,
      "NavteqLinkId":"771096842",
      "PrimaryLocation":null,
      "SecondaryLocation":null,
      "FirstArticleCity":null,
      "SecondCity":null,
      "EventType":"AccidentsAndIncidents",
      "EventSubType":"Shoulder Lane",
      "MapEncodedPolyline":null
   }
]
```

Events Object

```
public class Events
{
    public string LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public float Latitude { get; set; }
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
    public string PlannedEndDate { get; set; }
    public string Reported { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public object CountyName { get; set; }
    public string Severity { get; set; }
    public string RoadwayName { get; set; }
    public string DirectionOfTravel { get; set; }
    public object Description { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string LanesAffected { get; set; }
    public object LanesStatus { get; set; }
    public object LcsEntries { get; set; }
    public string NavteqLinkId { get; set; }
    public object PrimaryLocation { get; set; }
    public object SecondaryLocation { get; set; }
    public object FirstArticleCity { get; set; }
    public object SecondCity { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; }
    public string EventSubType { get; set; }
    public object MapEncodedPolyline { get; set; }
}
```

Code

```
ObservableCollection<Events> events = new ObservableCollection<Events>();
Events events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Events>(json);
lvEvents.ItemsSource = events;
```

xaml

```
 <ListView x:Name="lvEvents" ItemsSource="{Binding Events}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <Label Text="{Binding RegionName}" ></Label>
          </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>                
 </ListView>
```

Error i am receiving

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Project.View.Events' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>       To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>       Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: Could you format your json so its readable please?

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Events>(json)` should be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Events>>(json);`

Comment: Your json having list of Events `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Events>>(json);`

Comment: Did you read the error message and double checked how your JSON looks and what the deserialization expects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON is a list of objects. You're trying to deserialize it as a single object.

Try doing something like:

```
List<Events> events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Events>>(json);
lvEvents.ItemsSource = events;
```

If you want to be able to modify the list later, and have those updates reflected in the UI, you should use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead:

```
ObservableCollection<Events> events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Events>>(json);
lvEvents.ItemsSource = events;
```

---

Your `Events` class actually represents a single event, and you should probably rename it to `Event`.